# HTML class not being recognized

Tags: html, css

This code works as expected however when I try to change the css from affecting the div overall to just the class it doesn't seem to work. I've looked at the syntax but I can't seem to find any errors.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica”, sans-serif;

}

.test {
  background: #0d0e0d;
  height: 32px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>WEBSITE</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class=“test”></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `“` and `”` is not the same as `"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have some wierd double quotes in your `<div class=“test”></div>`. Replace them with regular double quotes and your code is working :

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>WEBSITE</title>
            <style>
                *{
                    margin: 0;
                    font-family: "Helvetica”, sans-serif;
                }
                .test {
                    background:#0d0e0d;
                    height:32px;
                    width:100vw;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="test"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Those are smart quotes.

Comment: Well, I guess they're too smart for the browsers :)

Comment: Yeah, they're a bit snooty.

Answer (score 2):

Try
     `<div class="test"></div>`

instead `<div class=“test”></div>`.

`“”` are smart quotes, while `classname` should be in `""` quotes

Answer (score 2):

You are using the incorrect quotation marks for a start. use `"` instead of `“`.

Also, you need to understand CSS specificity. If you declare a style for your `div` tag, any style associated with the class `test` will take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `class=“test”` you should change to `class="test"` and on the `font-family` as well, this code will work:

```html
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>WEBSITE</title>
            <style>
                *{
                    margin: 0;
                    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
                }
                .test {
                    background:#0d0e0d;
                    height:32px;
                    width:100vw;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="test"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```