# jquery .val() is returning undefined

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery that is returning undefined for one value but all other fields are OK.
Please be patient as I've checked the code many times but cannot find the problem.
The "sm" is returning undefined but name & email are OK.

## Why is this?

```
<html>
<br>
    <form>
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <br><br>
    Message:<br>
    <input type="text" id=”sm”>
    <br><br>
    <button id="submitform">Add Record</button>
    </form> 
    <p id="form-response">
    <p id="form-response-2">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>         
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitform").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Button has been clicked');
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var  email = $("#email").val();
    var  serverlessmessage = $("#sm").val();
    console.log(serverlessmessage);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'https://myurl.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v1/',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'serverlessmessage': serverlessmessage
      }),
      success: function(res,status) {
        $('#form-response').html('<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Record has been added...</div>');
    $('#form-response-2').html(res.body);
    console.log(res.body);
    console.log(status);
      },
      error: function() {
        $('#form-response').html('<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Something went wrong... We are working on it!</div>');
      }
    });
  })
});  
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input type="text" id=”sm”>` Looks like sm doesn't have actually quotes around it, but some other characters. It might be causing your html to be malformed. Try retyping your id attribute and save the file again.

Comment: maybe the quotes in sm cause issue. see `<input type="text" id=”sm”>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML class not being recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957500/html-class-not-being-recognized)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your `<input type="text" id=”sm”>` to `<input type="text" id="sm">`. You can use only single quote or double quote when you add an ID.

Comment: Thanks so much...I did not see that the id had the wrong surrounding characters